# automatically minimized chat tabs

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, chat, facebook-java-api, facebook-ui

We must call fu.init in hideFlashCallback to pause our game. When the user is in the another page to open chat tabs to our game,  the game will pause automatically.

Is there a method like FB API or something at the beginning of the loading game, 
automatically minimized chat tabs, so as to solve our problem?